# Pull data from CRM online using Web API

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm

I've created a webpage that will be used as a survey for end users to submit a review of how the helpdesk technician did with resolving a ticket. I've built the webpage using HTML, CSS, JS, and PHP. The page currently needs to pull 2 things from Dynamics 365: Users name and the company. I currently pass the ticket # via the URL which I plan to use as the value in a lookup (somehow).

I think that I need to use the Dynamics API somehow to get access to pull data from the form but I am not sure how to go about that. I found this post online https://functionalthoughts.com/dynamics-365-web-api-retrieve-data-javascript/
which I think is only for web resources created inside of CRM.

Here is an image of what I currently have:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G96l9.png)
and the value that I have passed via URL [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mvk7.png)
The end goal would be to pull the value of the name and company fields in Dynamics 365 Online.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, but your question is too vague, probably it will be closed by other people. Try to write some code (that are many tutorials if you google) and if you are stuck on something specific and can't find a solution feel free to write a question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without full context of your application, I can only give you high level pointers.

Before anything,
You need to authenticate to Dataverse (the engine that is hosting the data your after).  That means you need a an identity + JWT Token to auth.
This is the more complicated part, depending on how your managing access to your site and if your intending to allow dataverse to manage data access security.

To do that, in php, your going to want to start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries#web-application and read up the Python path for MSAL.

Once you have that you will either use a S2S app ( ConfidentialClient app ), or user identity auth ( publicclient app. )

*For explanation sake,* I am going to *assume* that you created a Confidential app to work with.  In Dataverse this type of login identity is called an "Application User"

Now you need add the application user to Dataverse and grant it permission to read the data you want. You should work with the admin of the dataverse instance to get that setup.  if your trying to solo it :) there is a good blog on how to do this here: https://powermaverick.dev/2020/08/10/create-application-user-in-dataflex-pro-cds/ Dont forget to grant your user a security role that can access the data your after.

Next,
You said you want to query by Ticket ID, again *assuming* that ticket id is in dataverse, you need to create an alternate key for the field that contains the ticket to be able to query on it.
you can find info on how to do that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/define-alternate-keys-entity

Ok, now that you have a user to work with and can create a token, and you have an alt key on the column your trying to query on, you just need to form the query to dataverse.

General info on how to form and call queries in dataverse can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api a specific example of retrieving via alt key can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/retrieve-entity-using-web-api#retrieve-using-an-alternate-key

Now that you have all the setup done, and once you have formed your query, you will need to generate the token and add it to the authorization header of the request and send over.

That should get you data back.